# How can I use windows movie maker after end of support on windows essential

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-movie-maker

I am using windows 10 Pro. I was looking for **Windows Movie Maker** and find out that is has become a part of the **Windows Essentials**. So I went on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13785/essentials-2012-release-notes) page to download the Windows Essential. But they said that

> Windows Essentials 2012 suite reached the end of support on January 10, 2017.
>   It is no longer available for download.

But I want to download and use windows Movie maker. Is there any way to do this after the end of support of Microsoft from Windows Essential?

Comment: Windows Essential does not run on Windows 10. See the link you quoted.

Comment: Windows 10 support all the almost all the softwares of windows 7 and windows 8. So I think it must also be supported by windows 10. By the way from 10 Jan, no one can download the essentials, no matter windows 7 or 8 or 10. I am looking for a solution to use Windows Movie Maker after all this.

Comment: There isn't one. That page used to say "Movie Maker will soon be available from Windows Store for Windows 10 users." but that statement has been removed by Microsoft.

Comment: OK. Now what? Is there no other way ?

Comment: [windows 10 movie maker replacement](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+movie+maker+replacement)

Comment: That link is about 2 years old, and lead me [there](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18614/windows-essentials). That says the same.  :(

Comment: That link I gave you has search results for alternative programs you can use instead of Movie Maker.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, I think it's time to move on from Windows Movie Maker.

Comment: If you want to ask about alternatives then please ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I confirmed thre years ago, there is nothing preventing you from installing it on Windows 10, except now the download isn't available.  Even wrote an answer, might have been for Windows 8, but it still applies

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is wlsetup-web.exe, which used to be available from Microsoft, and is not hard to find elsewhere if you search for it.

I had saved a copy, was able to use it to install Live Essentials on my father-in-law's new Windows 10 machine a few weeks after the nominal end of support from MS. I'd be curious to know if that approach still works.

Comment: Can you please give me the link.

Comment: I got my copy from Microsoft before the end of support. http://www.download3k.com/Install-Windows-Live-Movie-Maker-2011.html is the first plausible source I find with https://www.google.com/search?q=wlsetup-web.exe, but there are probably others.